# How to see backtrace of an uncaught exception using xdebug and IntelliJ / PHPStorm?

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

I have set up remote debugging on a guest OS in a Virtual Machine. Breakpoints work, but exceptions display on the rendered screen if one is reached. What I want is for the exception to be "caught" so I can explore the backtrace at the point of the error inside the IntelliJ debugger. Is this possible? What do I need to enable to make this happen?

*Note: the profiler is turned off, and almost everything is set to its default in xdebug. The Host and Guest OSs are Windows.*

Comment: Have you seen these articles: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+PhpStorm+Debugger#UsingthePhpStormDebugger-BreakingwhenThingsBreakExceptionBreakpoints 2) http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/12/just-in-time-debugging-and-php-exception-breakpoints-with-phpstorm-and-xdebug/

Comment: One important thing to note is that the auto-complete in IntelliJ is case sensitive.

Comment: Where? It could be just your settings...

Comment: It is just my settings, but they were default settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create "exception breakpoints" to catch exceptions at runtime**
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+PhpStorm+Debugger#UsingthePhpStormDebugger-BreakingwhenThingsBreakExceptionBreakpoints

I added `Exception`, `Warning`, and `Notice`.

Note: the **JIT** mode for XDebug, while providing just in time exception handling, does not allow the use of breakpoints, so this did not directly address my need.